# How can a Chrome extension access the HTTP headers of the active tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-headers

**Question:** I'm making a Chrome extension that, when the browser action is invoked, needs the HTTP headers of the current page in the active tab. What is the best way to access such headers?

**Unsatisfactory solution:** I'm aware of the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). However, that API is structured as listeners for different webRequest actions (e.g. when a request is sent or when a response returns); it does not, from what I can tell, allow you to simply query for the headers of the current page.

Thus, in order to use that API, it seems like I'd need to have a background script that's listening for any HTTP responses and storing the headers into some sort of map from tab IDs to headers. Then, the browser action just has the background script look up the headers for the active tab's ID.

**That seems very heavyweight and convoluted. Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such an API - headers are properties of requests, not tabs so if you want headers, you don't have much choice but to track requests. Even then, requests and tabs map rather poorly and non-uniquely.

Comment: As a couple datapoints unfortunately supporting this conclusion, I just downloaded relevant extensions and looked at their source.

HTTP Headers (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/mhbpoeinkhpajikalhfpjjafpfgjnmgk/related?hl=en) uses exactly the ugly, contrived solution I described.

Live HTTP Headers (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?hl=en) can't give any info on already loaded tabs, only on ones opened after starting the extension.